# Error: Warning!rename(/var/www/html/pub/media/tmp/catalog/product)

Tags: magento2, s3, amount

I am using Magento 2.1 and have configured it to store media files in an S3 bucket. However, when I try to upload a product image, I encounter the following errors:

[image]

Despite these errors, I can see the product images listed and accessible.

Could you please provide some guidance on resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the permissions by using these commands  in the root directory of the project:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/

sudo chown -R rana:rana .
```